# Data dependency and consistency

Tags: ruby, dependencies, uml, dependency-management, data-consistency

I'm developing a quite large (for me) ruby script for engineering calculations. The script creates a few objects that are interconnected in a hierarchical fashion.

For example one object (Inp) contains the input parameters for a set of simulations. Other objects (SimA, SimB, SimC) are used to actually perform the simulations and each of them may generate one or more output objects (OutA, OutB, OutC) that contain the results and produce the actual files used for the visualization or analysis by other objects and so on.

The first time I perform and complete all the simulations all the objects will be fully defined and I will have a series or files that represent the outputs for the user.

Now suppose that the user needs to change one of the attributes of Inp. Depending on which attribute has been modified some simulations will have to be re-run and some object OutX will be rendered invalid otherwise the consistency would be loss as the outputs would not correspond to the inputs anymore.

I would like to know whether there is a design pattern that would facilitate this process. Also I was wondering whether some sort of graph could be used to visually represents the various dependencies between objects in a clear way.

From what I have been reading (this question is a year old) I think that the Ruby `Observable` class could be used for this purpose. Every time a parent object changes, it should send a message to its children so that they can update their state.
Is this the recommended approach?

I hope this makes the question a bit clearer.

Comment: I read you question twice and I'm still not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I fully understand your question, but the problem of stages which depend on results of previous stages which in turn depend on results from previous stages which themselves depend on result from previous stages, and every one of those stages can fail or take an arbitrary amount of time, is as old as programming itself and has been solved a number of times.

Tools which do this are typically called "build tools", because this is a problem that often occurs when building complex software systems, but they are in no way limited to building software. A more fitting term would be "dependency-oriented programming". Examples include `make`, `ant`, or Ruby's own `rake`.